# Sending big picture style push notification from ionic dashboard

Tags: push, ionic3

I am using phonegap-plugin-push to send push in my ionic 3 app.
Normal notifications are working fine. I want to send big picture style notification from ionic dashboard. How can I do it? Which payload should be used in dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it. Push plugin has no check for payload. I added a check & it worked.